# Style "Comma" doesn't work unless edited manually

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macros that opens some workbook and puts some data inside it, after putting  a piece of data in a cell it edits its style as `.Style = "Comma"` (make space separators between numerals).

However, when I open that file I see only some the cells with "Comma" style, while other cells have no separators at all. If I select a cell with no visible separators, but mouse cursor at the formula area and click enter, the style does change to "Comma".

I tried to immitate it with `.Cells(i, j).Calculate`, but to no avail.

Why doesn't the style change for some of the cells and how to make it change inside macros?

PS I already have an automatic calculation in settings. Changing the style to "Comma" manually (clicking `000` icon doesn't work either - only works after I put cursor inside the cell's formula and click enter).

**EDIT**: I save file as `xlsx`. The code isn't that important. It consists of `Application.Open(filePath)` and `resultWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(i, j).Value = someValue`.

Comment: could you post more of your code? what are you saving the file as(.csv, .xlsx)?

Comment: It sounds like they're in there as text. Re-entering them will cause Excel to evaluate back to a numeric value which picks up the format/style.

Comment: Try replacing `someValue` with `CDec(someValue)` or even `CDec(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(someValue))` to be totaly sure

Comment: Select one of the errant cells. Expand the width. Make sure it is not Aligned Left, Right or Centered. If the number automatically aligns left, then it's text not numeric and this will be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your 'numbers' are being stored as text. Number formatting and styles such as 'Comma' will not work on Text.

The following would convert all numbers (and formula!) into numeric amounts that can be formatted / styled. You might want to restrict the range further in order to not impact areas containing formulae:

```
With Worksheets("sheet 1")
    .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I store my large numbers as `Variant`. Could it have affected it? I take it I'd better store them as `Double`, since they have the same range, right? And there will be no problem of styling after that.